# Installing libpoco and NPM conflict

Tags: c++, node.js, ubuntu, npm, poco-libraries

I've got Ubuntu 18.04 on my machine. I need to work on two projects: first on C++, second: front-end app with Angular which use for development mode NPM and Node.js.
The question is when I try to configure my environment with executing POCO it's killing NPM and the other way round NPM causes the same with POCO.

```
sudo app-get install libpoco-dev
sudo apt-get install libssh-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

After it I can see that symbolic links of POCO disappeared 
if I'm trying to reinstall POCO - it starts to delete NPM.

The question is - is it possible to fix -> or better that application environment will be on different servers? Thanks

Comment: It's a possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408425/trying-to-install-debian-package-npm-makes-apt-get-to-remove-libssl-dev

Comment: As described in the duplicate I also recommend to not use a nodejs and npm version from package manager. Install it manually